# Vue2 class based data property is not reactive

Tags: vuejs2, reactive, vue-class-components

I was using typescript in a vue2 class based components. sampleData prop is not reactive in a component while using a custom type KeyValuePair.

```
export type KeyValuePair<T> = {
  [key in string | number]: T;
};

<template>
<div>
<!-- remains empty even after sampleData is updated ! -->
 {{ sampleData }} 
</div> 
<template>

<script>
@Component()
export default class Sample extends Vue {

sampleData: KeyValuePair<string> = {}; 

//assume it gets called somehow
sampleMethod() {
   this.sampleData['0'] = 'sample data';
  }
}
</script>
```

Also tried to access sampleData prop from a getter but still not working.
Any solutions or suggestions might be helpful!

Comment: [Change Detection Caveats](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VueJS cannot detect property addition or deletion in objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects). And since the `0` key is not present in your sample data at runtime, adding it later will not yield the result you expect.

You will need to use `Vue.set` to achieve what you want:

```
sampleMethod() {
   Vue.set(this.sampleData, '0', 'sample data');
  }
}
```

Comment: Its also working,
`const key = 0;
this.sampleData = { ...this.sampleData, [key]: 'sample data' }
`